# How actually google count bounce rate? and specifically for my site scenario

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate

I am running one job portal. We are adding lots of jobs in our site and allow job seekers to apply for job within our site and do all rest process.

But In last week we have done collaboration with some companies to import jobs directly from their portal. We are importing 500+ jobs daily from given API by those companies.

For imported jobs we just allow job seeker to click on apply button and then we  redirecting job seeker to that company/3rd party site where actual job is located. So here for imported jobs our task is allow job seeker to open job , click on apply and then job seeker will be redirected to that 3rd party site for rest process.

So for all imported jobs , user stays 4-5 seconds only in our site. Does this will be consider as bounce rate? I have fear that if 100 user comes on site and stay only for 5 seconds and then redirect to 3rd party site will increase our site bounce rate and may be it can affect our SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For imported jobs we just allow job seeker to click on apply button and then we redirecting job seeker to that company/3rd party site where actual job is located.

There are mostly two kinds of understanding of bounce rate:

- some understand it like an amount of user clicking the back-button and going back from the page back to the search results,
- some other understand this like just going away from the given page (to other host).

In any case, going away isn't a positive user metric and all admins, independently of how they understand bounce rate, try to hide this going away, calling *clickout*. Look at any coupon site, how they do it.

You shoud try to hide your clickouts too, because your job detail pages have bad user metrics - people come, read and quickly leave the page.

Comment: Ok so you mean I should apply click-out strategy here?

Comment: i would do it definitely. Imagine, how Google sees it: visitors come int and just in short seconds amount they are away. With this user behavior Google will mean, your site isn't relevant to your targeted topic.